# RefTeX won't find bibliography file

Tags: emacs, reftex

I am using the latest Aquamacs on MacOS (and I am wondering why all these emacs-related questions are posted in tex.stackexchange.com and not in emacs.stackexchange.com).

I hope, I have configured my Emacs correct.  At least, this are the related definitions in `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq reftex-extra-bindings t)
(require 'reftex)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(require 'bibtex)
(bibtex-set-dialect 'biblatex)
(setq LaTeX-biblatex-use-Biber t)
(setq TeX-command-BibTeX "Biber")
(setq reftex-bibliography-commands
      '("bibliography" "nobibliography" "addbibresource")) 
(setq reftex-bibpath-environment-variables
      '(".:~/lib/texmf/bibtex/bib//:/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bib//:/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib//"))
; (reftex-use-external-file-finders t)
(setq reftex-external-file-finders
      '(("tex" . "kpsewhich -format=.tex %f")
    ("bib" . "kpsewhich -format=.bib %f")))
```

Emacs starts without complaint.

Next, I set up this MWE (just to be complete ...) as file `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{computer.bib}

\begin{document}

% Waiting to insert \cite{} here

\end{document}
```

I added the line `\addbibresource{computer.bib}` in the usual way: <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> `addbi` <kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>.  At this point, by pressing the <kbd>TAB</kbd>, Emacs completes the command to `\addbibresource` and inserts this LaTeX-command into the buffer, while still in the Minibuffer, I am asked for options.  I skipped that question, by pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> again.  Now Emacs asks (still in the minibuffer) for the bibliography file to use.  I typed `com`<kbd>TAB</kbd> and Emacs again completed to the full filename `computer.bib`, which I inserted by <kbd>RET</kbd>.

I suspect, that Emacs knew about the existence of `~/lib/texmf/bibtex/bib/JB/computer.bib` and therefore was able to complete its filename, because I defined `reftex-bibpath-environment-variables` (as seen above).

Emacs is also instructed to automatically scan the LaTeX files.  Hence, at this moment the auto-generated file `auto/test.el` shows:

```lisp
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "test"
 (lambda ()
   (TeX-add-to-alist 'LaTeX-provided-package-options
                     '(("fontenc" "T1") ("biblatex" "backend=biber" "style=numeric")))
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "semiverbatim")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "minted")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "Verbatim")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "Verbatim*")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "BVerbatim")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "BVerbatim*")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "LVerbatim")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "LVerbatim*")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "SaveVerbatim")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "VerbatimOut")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "hyperref")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "hyperimage")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "hyperbaseurl")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "nolinkurl")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "path")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-braces-local "url")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims-local "path")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims-local "Verb")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-macros-with-delims-local "url")
   (TeX-run-style-hooks
    "latex2e"
    "scrbook"
    "scrbook10"
    "fontenc"
    "biblatex")
   (LaTeX-add-bibliographies
    "computer"))
 :latex)
```

I am lucky, that the second last entry shows the correct bibliography file `"computer"`.  A quick test in the terminal/shell gives

```
<funnyprompt>:~$ kpsewhich bib computer.bib
/Users/tmjb/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib/JB/computer.bib
<funnyprompt>:~$ grep texstudio `kpsewhich bib computer.bib`
@Online{texstudio, 
                 url = {http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html},
```

This should proof that the file exists and contains an entry with the desired key "texstudio".

---

**EDIT: `~/lib/` expands in my case to `/Users/tmjb/Library/`.**

---

Next I move the cursor beneath `\begin{document}` and start to insert the `\cite`-command (again in the usual way): <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> (this is a shortcut for me, same as <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>).  While in the minibuffer, RefTeX asks me to insert the regular expression.  I insert `texstudio`, which I happen to know to exist in that given bibliography file. After pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> Emacs complains `Sorry, no matches found`.  The cursor leaves the Minibuffer and is still waiting in the main buffer, but no text is inserted, not even the already defined command `\cite`.

The `*Message*`-buffer says:

```
Making completion list...
   (?=Help)

Scanning bibliography database test.bib
Sorry, no matches found
```

Why the heck does Emacs want to scan `test.bib`?  This file does not exist anywhere.  Neither was it defined anywhere (including the LaTeX file nor the emacs configuration files)!

What did I miss in my configuration, to have Emacs scanning the bibliography file, it was able to complete its filename.

---

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Arash Esbati, I replaced `~` with the expanded path `/Users/tmjb`, finally I even restarted my emacs, than it worked!

I deleted the `\addbibliography{...}` entries in my file and reentered the bibliography files either be adding one big `\bibliography{tuc-thesis,latex-base,typographie,computer}` line (each of the listed files was completed in the minibufer) and afterwards by four `\addbibresource{}` again.  I typed <kbd>C-cC-n</kbd> to rescan the LaTeX file.  I than checked the auto file.  Surprisingly, it contained only three of the four bibliography files.  Regardless how I set up my file, only those bibliography files, which were not located in the local directory, where listed in the auto file.

I was than able, to insert an `\cite{}` command in the master file.  This is so far a step into the right direction :-)

After having successfully inserted a `\cite` into the master file, I was also able, to insert `\cite`s into the sub files.

What still isn't functioning correct, is that auto-completion of the labels does not work for bibliographies, that are not located in the local directory.  But I think, I can live with that for the moment!

Comment: I'm not on macOS, but does `/Users/tmjb/Library/` expand to `~/lib/`?

Comment: @ArashEsbati my MacOS is quite a Unix-like system.  So `~` expands to the home directory of my login `tmjb`, which is `/Users/tmjb/`.  As I was used to have a `~/lib/` directory in my home, I linked `~/Library/` to `~/lib`.  So Yes, `/Users/tmjb/Library` and `~/lib/` are identical.

Comment: Ok, my last guess is to use the absolute path like `(setq reftex-bibpath-environment-variables '(".:/Users/tmjb/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib//"))` and try it again.

Comment: @ArashEsbati After restarting the emacs it worked much better.  On the first try, I wasn't able to insert `\cite`s in sub files, but after reinserting the `\addbibresource` again, ... It worked even in the sub files.  I've edited my question, but I really would love to mark your answer with the green solved checkmark!  Thank you so much!